# Android and nRF51822 communication

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to communicate between a nRF51822 and android device, but in middle of the communication, the nRF51822 invokes
UartService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED and gets disconnected. If any of you have faced similar problems, please shed some light into the problems.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like nRF51822 crashes, from my experience.